# Interior, closure, and boundary of an infinite sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If I am given a non-constant countably infinite sequence in a compact set of $\mathbb{R}$, is there a general way to find its closure, interior, and boundary? I know Bolzano–Weierstrass tells us that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has convergent subsequence, but I am not sure how to proceed from there.

I guess I just don't quite understand the concept of interior, closure, and boundary in the context of sequences since I've only seen them used with specific sets and metrics.

Comment: Interiors, closures, and boundaries are properties of sets, not sequences.  But we frequently use sequences to probe the characteristics if sets.  Now if your set is defined as being all the points of a sequence, then this set may or may not have these properties (i.e. a closure, a boundary, an interior, etc)

Comment: Yes! It is defined to be the points of the sequence

Comment: What is the specific question? There isn't a general way to 'find' closures, etc. of sets. You make a guess and prove it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general approach that will work for every such sequence.   As an example consider that there is a countably infinite sequence $ \{ x_i \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} $ that generates $ \mathbb{Q} $.  Consider the compact set $ [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R} $ and restrict the sequence $ \{y_j\} = \{x_i\} \bigcap [0,1] $, which generates the set of all $ \mathbb{Q} $ which appears in the compact set $ [0,1] $, $ \mathbb{Q} \bigcap [0,1] $ (think of it like a subsequence of the one that creates the rationals; we step through every point of the rational numbers but choose only points that appear in the desired interval).

So what can be said about this set?  Well it's dense in $ [0,1] $ for the same reason $ \mathbb{Q} $ is dense in $ \mathbb{R} $ and so the closure of $ \{y_j\} $ is all of $ [0,1] $.  Accordingly the interior of $ \{y_j\} $ is empty and every point is a boundary point.

This should demonstrate that there is a wealth of diverse countably infinite sequences you can develop even on compact subsets of a larger space like $ \mathbb{R} $.  Every such sequence needs to be analyzed individually unless you have some stronger restrictions.